# 12.10 on HP tx1000 problems

Tags: 12.10

Ubuntu 12.10 is running very slowly on my old hp tx1000. Graphics are flickering, text cut, icons broke, lines across the screen, wifi doesn't work. Did I mention it's very slow.

Should I throw the computer away or put 12.04 back on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend to put 12.04 back on as it more stable lts version for 5 years of support.Dash is no doubt working faster in 12.04 and there are almoust no graphic issues.Also the amount of available apps is bigger for 12.04.For now 12.10 is quite unstable.They will fix it in few mounths i guess.  By now if you still preffer to use 12.10 release check out this link maybe it will be usefull http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/make-unity-more-responsive-in-ubuntu.html I would recommend installing gnome fallback desktop environment or any other gnome 3.6 i heard a lot faster then unity. Try  xfce desktop wich is faster and stable or chose pupy linux distro..i guess its based on ubuntu and optimized for the older pc-s.